# Translation of IT terms like “close”, “next”, “search”, etc

Tags: vocabulaire, informatique

I need to translate a lot of terms in a IT-application like button labels:

- Close
- Next
- Exit
- Search
- etc.

Can anyone translate these or is there any site with a list of common terms for French?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most common button labels that come to my mind would be the following:

- **Close** = **Fermer**
- **Exit** = **Quitter** (Small difference between this and Close. I'd say you should use this one when leaving/closing some kind of workflow or the program itself, and Close when just closing a window/confirmation message)
- **Cancel** = **Annuler**
- **Previous** = **Précédent**
- **Next** = **Suivant**
- **Search** = **Rechercher** (This one can be used either to activate a search mode or to apply a entered text for the search, both are fine)
- **Confirm** = **Confirmer**
- **Apply** = **Appliquer**
- **Accept/Agree** = **Accepter**
- **Decline** = **Refuser**
- **Enable** = **Activer**
- **Disable** = **Désactiver**

Another label you might see quite often in French is **"Valider"**, it has more or less the same usage than a **"Confirm"/"Ok"** button, just remember that it's not exactly meaning the same thing as **"Validate"** in English.

Comment: Thank you very much for this effort ! that is amazing. This should be payed.

Comment: I'll add some others. Browse => Parcourir, Save => Sauvegarder, Undo => Annuler, Edit => Editer/Modifier, Settings => Paramètres, Minimise => Réduire, Maximise => Agrandir

Comment: For specific queries, you may also try [this](http://granddictionnaire.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Two options.

1. Change your browser or operating system into French for a while and find out the corresponding terms that way. It's easy with Chrome or a Mac.
2. Have a browse through the FR-ER translation projects on the crowdsourcing site [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/projects), which constantly deals with these terms.